# How to hint Javadoc about generic parameter of the base class?

Tags: java, javadoc

I've got the following setup:

Base class:

```
class GenericBuilder<T extends GenericBuilder> {
    /**
     * Some documentation.
     */
    public T withParam1(ParamType param) { /* ... */ }
}
```

Two derived classes:

```
public class ConcreteBuilder1 extends GenericBuilder<ConcreteBuilder1> {
    // some unique parameters
}

public class ConcreteBuilder2 extends GenericBuilder<ConcreteBuilder2> {
    // some unique parameters
}
```

I introduced the `GenericBuilder` to avoid code duplication between two builders that are currently derived from it.

In the generated Javadoc HTML pages the method appears as `T withParam1(ParamType param)` for each class, instead of `ConcreteBuilder1 withParam1(ParamType param)` and `ConcreteBuilder2 withParam1(ParamType param)`. I also noticed, that the generated page claims, that the ConcreteBuilders are extending `Object`, possibly because `GenericBuilder` is a package-level class, but making it public contradicts what I want to accomplish and does not really solve my problem.

The question is: how can I give a hint to Javadoc, that T has a very concrete meaning in the context of the ConcreteBuilders?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by `In the generated Javadoc`?  What is generating this javadoc?  Where is the javadoc?

Comment: I'm using gradle to generate HTML documentation from javadocs included in my source files.

Comment: What file has the wrong javadoc?

Comment: Two of them: one describing `ConcreteBuilder1` and the second describing `ConcreteBuilder2`.

Comment: I've played with this a bit on my own but can't achieve what you're looking for, sorry.

Comment: Thank you for trying! ;)